# Update SQL LocalDB without overwriting data

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-express, localdb

I'm developing a c#.net site, with a LocalDB via Visual Studio 2013.

I have a number of stored procedures and these may change in the future, but there will definitely be some new additions as the project develops.

The live site/server will be collecting new date on a regular basis and therefore will become out of synch with dev copy. Additionally, I have a number of stored procedures in use, and this will likely need tweaking in the future. There will also definitely be new stored procedures needed as the project develops.

### So, my question is... How do I make these changes / additions without overwriting the data in the live site database?

As a follow on.. Would it be better to use the 'full' version of SQL Express rather than LocalDB???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest you to create a table in the database called `DBVersion` with Column `VID`. Then create a MS Access DB(since it is more handy) and store newly added procedures in it:

Table in AccessDB has following columns:

```
DBVersionID    NewQuery
```

When you create a new procedure, add it to the Access DB. Eg:

```
DBVersionID    NewQuery
1              CREATE PROC BLABLABLA
2              ALTER PROC ASDF
```

And whenever the application starts,

```
select NewQuery FROM AccessDB WHERE DBVersionID>(Select VID FROM DBVersion)
```

Execute each of them and update the `VID` with the `DBVersionID` of lastly executed `NewQuery`.

From now on, whenever you add new procedure, add them to the AccessDB and just replace the AccessDB file in every live clients.

Comment: Yikes! Thanks for the great solution. I was hoping it wouldn't be such a messy solution. Maybe I'll have to rethink things a little.

Comment: This is what I usually do in my projects. Trust me!! It is not that messy. You will know it when you implement it. You can create, alter or delete tables,columns,procs,etc. And updating DB at clients' systems won't be a headache.

Comment: Sorry, I didnt mean that your solution was a bad one. I meant, that I was hoping MS had already got this covered and that there was a built in solution in keeping with the full SQL version.

Comment: If you get any better solution, post an answer right here, my friend. So that I can get to used to it.